# NPAPI plugin - To access array object from Javascript

Tags: javascript, npapi, browser-plugin

I created a `NPAPI` plugin, but want to know which all methods in `NPClass` gets invoked in the below mentioned javascript code for line2 .

Also I want to know the method to access array index in the plugin .

1. `var tst = document.getElementById('test`');
2. `var name1 = tst[1];`

Answer (score 1):

It will call your `GetProperty` method; the `NPIdentifier` will either be an `IntIdentifier` with the value of `i` or a normal `StringIdentifier` with the numeric string matching `i`.